# Regression measurement error - Classic Errors in Variables assumption - command in R

Tags: r, regression, stata, measurement-error

I need to handle measurement error in independent variables. I have the CEV case i.e. that $$CoV(x_1^*, e_1) = 0$$ where $x_1^* = ability$ (a persons innate ability) and $x_1 = sat$ (a test score).

In stata I would use *eivreg* but what do I use in R?

See example here for how he did it in stata http://www.philender.com/courses/linearmodels/notes4/merror.html

---

To be precise, I have a situation where $colgpa = sat + u$ was my first regression but then we introduce $colgpa = ability + e_1 + u$ and we do the assumption that $Cov(ability, e_1) = 0$. We know from theory that

Comment: Here is a useful `R` blog that may answer your question: http://www.r-bloggers.com/errors-in-variables-models-in-stan/

Comment: @ZERO I am not allowed to use bayesian framework.